# Transaction Scope Isolation level and EF6

Tags: entity-framework

I am testing the EF6 isolation level but the test fails with:

```
Assert.AreEqual failed. Expected:<ReadUncommitted>. Actual:<Unspecified>.
```

The test:

```
public void TestIsolationLevelReadUncommitted()
{
  // Arrange
  using (
    new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required,
      new TransactionOptions {IsolationLevel = IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted}))
  {
    using (var context = new BoligEntities())
    {
      // Act
      context.GetDbConnection().Open();
      var isolationLevel = context.GetDbConnection().GetIsolationLevel();

      // Assert
      Assert.AreEqual(System.Data.IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted, isolationLevel);
    }
  }
}
```

The test doesn't make much sense but I am wondering why it fails.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, but I would guess that `Unspecified` means it will use the database default. If you're using SQL Server, the default will eventually be `READ UNCOMMITTED`, but `GetIsolationLevel()` simply does not return that piece of information. Maybe it will after you have performed `SaveChanges`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is plenty of posts around transaction scope and EF.
Actually add uncommitted read and nolock to your searches.

[Good basic explanation and example](http://www.luisrocha.net/2011/08/managing-transactions-with-entity.html)

FROM EF 6 on...
[EF transaction scope docu](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn456843#transactionScope)

Generally you dont need it.  ( there are exceptions)
and
 i hope i dont have to support the system that uses uncommitted reads. ;-)   **Filthy...**

good luck

Answer (score 1):

Transaction is not the same as database. Looks like you are checking Isolation level for open connection but not for running transaction. 
Generally speaking - you can open connection and run multiple transaction on this connection with different Isolation level.

```
using (var context = new MyEntities())
{
     using (var tran = context.Database.BeginTransaction(System.Data.IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted))
     {

         Assert.AreEqual(System.Data.IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted, tran.UnderlyingTransaction.IsolationLevel);
```